# Using the floor function to define a periodic function

Tags: graphing-functions

Is it possible to define the function defined in the following image using the floor function? If so, how?

[image]

**Update**

I tried your suggestion with Matlab's symbolic toolbox,

```
syms x clear
clear f
f(x)=abs(x-2*floor(x/2));
fplot(f(x),[0,8])
```

but I got the following picture, which is not correct.

[image]

Comment: Sure. Why do you want to use the floor function specifically?

Comment: $$\bigg|x-2\bigg\lfloor\frac x2\bigg\rfloor\bigg|$$

Comment: @RushabhMehta I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. See my update above. Did I interpret your symbolism correctly? Thanks.

Comment: @TomGrubb Because Matlab's Symbolic Toolbox will give the Laplace transform of a function defined by the floor function.

Comment: Try not including the 2 David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the fractional part $\{x\}$ to be
$$
x = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\{ x \right\}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le \left\{ x \right\} < 1
$$
note that it does not actually reach to $1$.

Then stretch and shift it so to obtain
$$
1 - 2\left\{ {{x \over 2}} \right\}
$$

Finally take the absolute value
$$
f(x) = \left| {\,1 - 2\left\{ {{x \over 2}} \right\}\,} \right| = \left| {\,1 - x + 2\left\lfloor {{x \over 2}} \right\rfloor \,} \right|
$$

[image: Sega_con_Floor]